# Listening for change in routerLink

Tags: angular, angular-router, router-outlet

I have some links that when clicked should open a component at a *router-outlet*. This component displays content based on the value in the routerLink.
Based on the code, whenever a user clicks a link provided by {{ note.title }},the *NoteContentComponent* should open at the router-outlet.

If i am at the root of the app: **localhost:4200** and click the link the app navigates to **localhost:4200/notes/*requiredid***, and opens the component. Which is all good. But next time when I click any other link the url in the address bar changes, but the new component does not show in the *router-outlet*.

```
<div class="container-fluid note-nav-container">
    <div class="row" style="height: 100%;">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 note-nav">
            <ul *ngIf="notes" class="note-list">
                <li *ngFor="let note of notes">
                    <a routerLink="/notes/{{note._id}}">
                        {{ note.title }}
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-12 content-container">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
       path: 'notes',
       children: [
           {
               path: ':id',
               component: NoteContentComponent
           }
       ]
    }
];
```

I think the problem is that when I click a link the second time, it sees that the app is already pointing to **/notes/:id**, and though the address changes, it does not bother opening the new component.

How can i work around this.

Comment: Could you post the main route definition?

Comment: How do you get you `:id`? With `this.route.snapshot` or Observable?

Comment: There will be no new component. The same component must display the value associated with the new ID. It can know the new ID because it's emitted by the ActivatedRoute.paramMap observable.

Comment: @jocactus Yes using snapshot

Comment: The snapshot, as its name indicates, contains a... snapshot of the route params at the moment when you read it. Don't use the snapshot. use the observable ActivatedRoute.paramMap observable, which emits every time the parameters change.

Comment: @JBNizet So how can I trigger functions in the same component when the url changes.

Comment: By subscribing to the ActivatedRoute.paramMap observable. If you don't know how to use observables, then stop what you're doing, and take some days learning how to use them. They're a hard concept to grasp, but are very much unavoidable when using Angular.

Comment: @KishoreKumar These are the only routes

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks it worked